# SQL query help needed using CASE statments

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create table temp (Name varchar(100), ColA int, ColB int, ColC int, ColD int)
insert into temp (name, ColA,ColB, ColC, ColD)
values ('aaaaaa',1,null,null, null)
,('bbbbbb',1,1,null,null)
```

```
select name,case 
    when ColA = 1 then 'some value'
    when ColB = 1 then 'Other value'
    when Colc = 1 then 'some2 value'
    when Cold = 1 then 'some3 value'
    end CaseValues
from temp
```

```
select * from temp
```

/*when you run this case statment I get only two record. But I need three records for each value matched as below:

```
    Name    CaseValues

1   Mayur   Some value
2   anubha  some vaule
3   anubha  other value
```

Comment: Your queries and your question don't seem to match. Can you correct either one to reflect what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: is there any other way to get three records using case statements

Comment: My point was that you are inserting "aaaaaa" and "bbbbb" and expecting "Mayur" and "Anubha". Also, why do you need 3 records? What is the purpose of the query?

Comment: A case expression is not going to create additional rows in the results set.

Comment: Your sample data has 2 rows but your desired output has 3. What are you trying to do? A case expression controls the value returned in a given column, it will not affect the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table V (value varchar(100), ColA int, ColB int, ColC int, ColD int)
insert into V values ('some value', 1, null, null, null)
    , ('Other value', null, 1, null, null)
    , ('some2 value', null, null, 1, null)
    , ('some3 value', null, null, null, 1)

select temp.Name, V.value
from temp
inner join V on V.colA = temp.ColA 
    or V.ColB = temp.ColB
    or V.ColC = temp.ColC
    or V.ColD = temp.ColD

Name    value
aaaaaa  some value
bbbbbb  some value
bbbbbb  Other value
```